# Concatenating rows of a table and a subquery with equal field names

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a table called `stuff` with columns `id` and `name`. Let's also say that I have a subquery that selects from a different table (let's call it `other_stuff`) the columns `id` and `name`.

At this point in my example, the result of `select * from stuff` and `select * from (<my subquery>)` will contain the same columns (but different rows).

Is there a way I can somehow "concat" both results, so I can do something like...

```
select *
from stuff

concat

(<my subqueryy>)

where name == "foobar"
```

...so that the `where` condition will match all `foobar` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is UNION ALL:

```
select t.* from (
  select * from stuff 
  union all 
  select * from <my subquery>
) as t
where t.name = "foobar"
```